# Method of finding out if jQuery is used in code

Tags: jquery

**Is there a quick way of searching through a block of code to find out if it contains any jQuery?**

Is it as simple as searching for the presence of a '$' or could that occur in other languages?

In my role I need to help reduce the usage of jQuery to an absolute minimum and ultimately stop using it all together so if I can search through new blocks of code presented to me for jQuery I can quickly get it sorted.

As an example, we have a block of code that appears to be 100% JS at first glance but contained within is small lines of jQuery. This was found by reading through the lines so as you can imagine I need a better way!

Comment: `$` can be anything, anything can assign something to `$` or `window.$`. You might remove jQuery from the included libraries and look for errors.

Comment: Delete jQuery and see what breaks :) `$` can be assigned to anything, not just jQuery, and likewise `jQuery` can be assigned to anything, not just `$`, so searching for either alone is not reliable.

Comment: try `if(jQuery)`

Comment: You will know if jQuery is loaded in page and if the $ is assigned to it checking `if(jQuery && $ === jQuery)`.
To check if jQuery is used you may try something like this: `jQuery = $ = () => alert('jQuery called.');` and look for alerts messages.

Comment: @SooriyaDasanayake that will tell you that jQuery *is* used, not *where*.

Comment: @Professore that will tell you that jQuery *is* used, not *where*.

Comment: @rory-mccrossan I know, but since I don't know any way to tell where jQuery is used I thought an approach to watch the moment in wich is used.

Comment: @Professore Just tried this... SO many alerts. This might just do the trick for what I need.